# Am I in the correct direction for solving this problem?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Virtual call centers are staffed by individuals working out of their homes. An airline is considering employing home agents, but only if their level of customer satisfaction is greater than $80\%$. A test was conducted with home servicing agents. In a sample of size 300 customers, 252 reported that they were satisfied with the service

A. The airline set up the test:
$$
  \begin{align*}
   H_0 &: p \leq 0.8  \\
   H_1 &: p > 0.8 
  \end{align*}  
$$
at level $\alpha = 0.05$ ; p is the true proportion among all customers who will be satisfied by service from home agent

Set up and sun this test, using significance level 
$$ \alpha =.05 $$. What conclusion do you reach?

$$
\begin{align*}
n = 300&, N =252 \\
H_0 &: p \leq 0.8  \\
H_1 &: p > 0.8 
\end{align*}
$$

Test statistic: One Group Proportion

$$Z = \frac{.84 - .8}{\sqrt{.8(1-.84)/300}} $$

From here I would compare it with the Z value at .05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your Z statistic to the Z critical value for a 5% significance. This Z critical value is 1.644 and your Z statistic is 1.732.. Since this is right tailed you compare whether your Z statistic is greater than Z critical. In this case it is, Since it is observed that z = 1.732 > z* = 1.64, it is then concluded that the null hypothesis is rejected...Additionally, The p-value is p = 0.0416, and since p = 0.0416 < .05, it is concluded that the null hypothesis is rejected.. Therefore, there is enough evidence to claim that the population proportion p is greater than po, at the .05 significance level... I'm on mobile so I can't format this nicely but hopefully that helps. In addition the denominator should be the null value (.8)

Comment: Which formula did you use to calculate the Z statistic 1.732? I used a one group proportions test.

Comment: Yes you have it right. But the denominator is the Null proportion (.8) not .84... so Square root ((.8(1-.8)/300))